# Why are my Pylot graphs blank?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pylot

I'm using Pylot 1.26 with Python 2.7 on Windows 7 64bit having installed Numpy 1.6.2 and Matplotlib 1.1.0. The test case executes and produces a report but the response time graph is empty (no data) and the throughput graph is just one straight line.

I've tried the 32 bit and 64 bit installers but the result is the same.

Comment: @hayden why do you think this will help?

Comment: I take it back, I incorrectly read that no graph was shown at all. What is your test case (perhaps this is a problem with your code)?

Comment: It's just a get to a url with 2 params. I think i need to resurect my poor python skills and have a look under the hood

Comment: what does `plot(range(12))` give you?

Comment: I get a graph - I don't think it's matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

I had the same identical problem. I spent sometime on it today debugging few things, I realized the problem with me was that the data collected to plot charts wasn't correct and i needed to adjust. What I did was just changing the time from absolute to relative and dynamically adjusting the range of the axis. I'm not that good in python and so my code doesn't look that good.